# How to select an item just by click on it in combobox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

My situation is i have a comb-Box which i fill with items that are integer values dynamically through javascript.

The problem is when i click on item to select it , It is still not selected , after clicking at that item, again i need to click outside the combo box to get it selected. I don't know why ?

My code to do so is (it's inside table) :

```
 <body onload="loadView();">
       <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
               <select id="mydropdown" name="mydropdown" onblur="comboItemselect(this)"></select>
             </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </body>
```

And how i fill the item in combo is like this :

```
   function loadView()
            {
                var sel = document.getElementById('mydropdown') // find the drop down
                for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { // loop through all elements
                    var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
                    opt.value = i; // set the value
                    opt.text = i; // set the text
                    sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
                }
            }

            /*When an item is selcted from CoboBox*/
            function comboItemselect(item)
            {
                var selectedItem = item.options[item.selectedIndex];   
              alert("selected item is : " +selectedItem);
            }
```

What i have done before in wpf or any other application was , i just clicked on the item to be selected in combobox and it was selected, but why i need to click once on the item and then again click  outside the combobox to get it selected ? 
  How to select item just by clikinng once on that combo box item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change event from onblur to onclick. it will work fine

```js
function loadView() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('mydropdown') // find the drop down
  for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { // loop through all elements
    var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
    opt.value = i; // set the value
    opt.text = i; // set the text
    sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
  }
}

/*When an item is selcted from CoboBox*/
function comboItemselect(item) {
  var selectedItem = item.options[item.selectedIndex];
  alert("selected item is : " + selectedItem.value);
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadView();">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="mydropdown" name="mydropdown" onchange="comboItemselect(this)"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: th problem with onclick is , as i click on the combo to open it, to see item it contains, the first item is selected immediately just by click on combobox, before i try to select the item

Comment: which browser are you using? becaus i am using chrome and my snippet working fine in my browser

Comment: even it works same in chrome, as i click oncombobox to open, it automtically selects the first item. I am not able to select the desired item

Answer (score 0):

You were close. All you need to do is change

```
var selectedItem = item.options[item.selectedIndex];
```

to

```
var selectedItem = item.value;
```

for any elemt you can access the attributes like id and value just by using

```
<variable>.id
<variable>.value
```

and as for the clicking outside, it is because you have it onBlur which means after losing focus. So it will call the function after you click off the the select box. What you can do is add it to the .click function. JQuery would be even better for this operation as you can do an `onClick` event to initialize your select and an `onChange` event to get the selected item